# Need div arrangement as shown in the screenshot

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, css-float

I am working on a chrome extension. There are n div blocks. This n number of div blocks depends upon the URL that I am going to visit. So on some pages the visible blocks may be 1,2,3,4,5 but on another they may be 1,5 or maybe 1,2,5.
So accordingly my `div's` should occupy the space and don't leave any blank space.

Output I need:

[image: Screenshot/Image Source]

This is what I've tried (also on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parag_bandewar/4dmc11jq/)), but the problem is the blank space below the red color.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
.One {
  background-color: Red;
  height: 200px;
}
.Two {
  background-color: Green;
  height: 400px;
}
.Three {
  background-color: Blue;
  height: 500px;
}
.Four {
  background-color: Orange;
  height: 700px;
}
.Five {
  background-color: Yellow;
  height: 200px;
}
.Six {
  background-color: Pink;
  height: 400px;
}
.Seven {
  background-color: Grey;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="One">
</div>
<div class="Two">
</div>
<div class="Three">
</div>
<div class="Four">
</div>
<div class="Five">
</div>
<div class="Six">
</div>
<div class="Seven">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really get much, your fiddle is very far from the desired output but if all you want is for the red box to occupy/extend to the empty space below then why not just change its height?

Comment: Becuase they should be dyanamic. If one of the div is removed, other div should take up that space

Comment: We need to know what, if any, requirements you have for how you want the different blocks to be arranged when some are not being displayed. It is relatively easy to get the blocks to flow into  the area which would be otherwise occupied by he particular not-shown blocks. However, *exactly* what it looks like will depend on how it is done. We need to know what you want, as it is, there are too many possible interpretations of how it should look.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<article>
  <section>
    <p class="sect1">1</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="sect2">2</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="sect3">3</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="sect4">4</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="sect5">5</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="sect6">6</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="sect7">7</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="sect8">8</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="sect9">9</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="sect10">10</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box !important;}

article {
 -moz-column-width: 10em;
 -webkit-column-width: 10em;
 -moz-column-gap: 1em;
 -webkit-column-gap: 1em; 

}

section {
 display: inline-block;
 margin:  0.25rem;
 padding:  1rem;
 width:  100%; 
 background:  #efefef;
}

p {
 min-width: 200px;
 margin:  1rem 0; 
}

.sect1{ min-height: 100px; }
.sect2{ min-height: 200px; }
.sect3{ min-height: 300px; }
.sect4{ min-height: 300px; }
.sect5{ min-height: 500px; }
.sect6{ min-height: 600px; }
.sect7{ min-height: 200px; }
.sect8{ min-height: 400px; }
.sect9{ min-height: 400px; }
.sect10{ min-height: 400px; }
```

Here's the Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/JPratik2712/huLkhpux/

Comment: This answer would be significantly improved by putting the code into a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Using a snippet also makes it more likely for it to be up-voted, because people can quickly verify that your code functions correctly. While snippets shouldn't always be used, for JavaScript/HTML/CSS based questions and answers they can significantly improve communicating both the problem and solution. When possible to use, a snippet is better than runable code examples that are off-site (e.g. JSFiddle).